# Dafny - Modify an Array by condition

Tags: dafny

Formally, the problem is given an array arr and an integer k, change arr[i] to -1 if and only if arr[i] > k.

So here's my attempt so far.

```
method replace(arr: array?<int>, k: int)
    modifies arr
    
    // precondition: non-null array
    requires arr != null && arr.Length > 0;
    requires forall i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length ==> arr[i] > 0

    // postcondition
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length ==> (old(arr[i]) > k ==> arr[i] == -1) && (old(arr[i]) <= k ==> arr[i] == old(arr[i]))
{
    var i := 0;
    while i < arr.Length
        // variant
        decreases arr.Length - i
        
        // invariants
        invariant 0 <= i <= arr.Length

        // ERROR HERE!
        invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i ==> (old(arr[j]) > k ==> arr[j] == -1) && (old(arr[j]) <= k ==> arr[j] == old(arr[j]))
    {
       if (arr[i] > k)
       {
         arr[i] := -1;
       }
        
       i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

Dafny is reporting an error in the second invariant of the while loop. The error is as follows:

ex2.dfy(140,12): Error: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.
ex2.dfy(140,12): Related message: loop invariant violation

I would appreciate some help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say something about array indices which you are not modifying. Notice second invariant of while loop. This dafny code verifies.

```
method replace(arr: array?<int>, k: int)
  modifies arr
  requires arr != null && arr.Length > 0
  requires forall i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length ==> arr[i] > 0
  ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length ==>
   (((old(arr[i]) > k) ==> arr[i] == -1) &&
    ((old(arr[i]) <= k) ==> arr[i] == old(arr[i])))
{
  var i := 0;
  while i < arr.Length
    decreases arr.Length - i
    invariant 0 <= i <= arr.Length
    invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i ==>
       (((old(arr[j]) > k) ==> arr[j] == -1) &&
       ((old(arr[j]) <= k) ==> arr[j] == old(arr[j])))
    invariant forall j :: i <= j < arr.Length ==> old(arr[j]) == arr[j]
  {
    if arr[i] > k {
      arr[i] := -1;
    }
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!
That was exactly what I was missing. Got to have that in mind always.
Have a good one :)